# Sitecore 7.2 - Solr 4 facet search for suggests - No results with hyphens in search word

Tags: solr, sitecore

I'm sending a request to Solr to receive suggests for a word that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mysearchindex/select?q=_templatename:Page&facet.field=pagecontent_t&facet.prefix=book&rows=0&facet=true&version=2.2&facet.sort=true
```

pagecontent_t is a computed field of type text, that is filled with content from Sitecore items.Its configuration:

```
<field fieldName="PageContent" returnType="text">Feature.Search.ComputedFields.PageContentField, Feature.Search</field>
```

Config of *_t fields in schema.xml:

```
<dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

It works for words without hyphens, but I get no results at all for word including a hyphen.

I tried using a copied field "pagecontent_s" of type string. Using this I get results with hyphens, but the whole pagecontent is resturned instead of just matching words for suggests.

What am I missing? What's the best way to get suggests to work with hyphens in the search word?

Comment: The analyzer chain for indexing is probably not the same as the one used for querying. Can you add `pagecontent_t` field definition in your post ?

Comment: Added the config of the pagecontent field to the first post.

Comment: I was talking about the corresponding Solr's fieldType definition (`text` in schema.xml).

Comment: Added config of *_t fields in schemal.xml.

Comment: These fields are mapped to `text_general` fieldType (not text sorry), this is what defines the `<analyser>` chain. Mats answer should be helpful, add the fieldType definition to your post if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to split words on the whitespace separating them, excluding other forms of punctuation, use a WhitespaceTokenizer for your field instead of the StandardTokenizer (or a WordDelimiterFilter somewhere in your chain).

Facets are generated over the tokens indexed, and if your tokens are split into smaller pieces than what you want, then that's what's being used to calculate facet values. Correct the processing to give the result you want (which seems to be that only white space should split tokens).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But shouldn't it work with the Keyword Tokenizer too?

Comment: No, the KeywordTokenizer keeps the input string as one, single, large token as you've discovered. If you give it "This is a sentence", the token stored will be `This is a sentence`. White a whitespace tokenizer, you'll get `This`, `is`, `a`, `sentence` (and if you apply a LowercaseFilter, the first token will be stored as `this`).

Comment: Using the WhitespaceTokenizer did the trick. Thanks a lot. The only problem is that with this I also get results with commas (like Tolkien,). Is there a way to configure the Solr to fiter these characters?

Comment: You can use a [MappingCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/charfilterfactories.html) in front of the Tokenizer to remove explicit characters you do not want, or you can use a PatternReplaceCharFilter to remove anything that's not a letter for example.